# Python "MemoryError" in AWS

Tags: python, amazon-ec2, spacy

when I trying to load spacy in script that gives the below error? Is it beacuse of meomry is full? or any other reason?

```
  Traceback (most recent call last):
        english_model = English()
      File "/home/ubuntu/.local/lib/python3.4/site-packages/spacy/language.py", line 257, in __init__
        add_vectors(self.vocab)
      File "/home/ubuntu/.local/lib/python3.4/site-packages/spacy/language.py", line 60, in <lambda>
        return lambda vocab: vocab.load_vectors_from_bin_loc(vec_path)
      File "spacy/vocab.pyx", line 436, in spacy.vocab.Vocab.load_vectors_from_bin_loc (spacy/vocab.cpp:10463)
      File "spacy/cfile.pyx", line 40, in spacy.cfile.CFile.alloc_read (spacy/cfile.cpp:1410)
      File "cymem/cymem.pyx", line 44, in cymem.cymem.Pool.alloc (cymem/cymem.cpp:1126)
    MemoryError
```

Comment: Based on the fact that the documentation of [`MemoryError`](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/exceptions.html#MemoryError) states: "Raised when an operation runs out of memory [..]" I'd say it's a fair chance that the operation runs out of memory. Or in other words: The memory is full.

Comment: @Matthias Thank you for your guidence

Comment: you can check memory usage from the aws console - you can also open another session to your instance and check the memory consumption while you run your script, you'll see if you fill up your memory or not

Answer (score 0):

you might be using 32 bit version of python or 32 bit version of packages with 64 bit python. Uninstall existing version of python and all packages and reinstall 
64 bit version of python and relevant packages.